# How to get and compare date and time of given files in python

Tags: python

Is there any handy functions can retrieve timestamp from given files or even compare them? My ideal usage would be like this:

```
time_diff = date(file_path_a) - date(file_path_b) # time_diff would be a formatted string such as 2days 3hrs 16 mins
```

I know there is a built-in datetime module in python, but I haven't found anything similar to my usage. And I know I can achieve similar effect by issuing os.stat(file_path) to get the timestamp, and transform them to the format I want. Just wondering if there are any more handy function to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import datetime, os
def mtime(filename):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(filename).st_mtime)
time_diff = mtime(file_path_a) - mtime(file_path_b)
```

… and then format the resulting `datetime.timedelta` object in the desired way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `time.ctime` and `os.path.getctime` or `getmtime` functions. If you prefer your own format for the time string use [time.strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) to do the formatting.

```
time.ctime(os.path.getctime('fileA') - os.path.getctime('fileB'))
```